# Avoid repeated columns from a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

My database contains a table `person` with these fields `username, name, online, visible, ...`

I have the following query to fetch the person

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN online = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN visible = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE online
    END AS online
FROM person
where id = SOMEID
```

I am trying to move the online/offline with respect to user-set visibility logic right into the query. Basically show online status depending on visibility status (If the user has chosen to be invisible, show offline even if the user is online).

This kind of works but with an issue. I get two repeated columns in the result of this query.

```
username | name | online | visible | ... | online
x        | x    | x      | x       | ... | x
```

For reasons not in my control I am stuck with using `SELECT *` instead of manually typing in the columns as `SELECT username, name, visible, ...`. Is there a way to exclude `online` field from `SELECT *`? Since it will be created by the CASE statement later.

Comment: Not really,  but you could create a view

Comment: Why are you stuck with the SELECT * ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, * means all the columns, there is no way to exclude a particular column from select *. May be you can name your column something else like "online_status" and use "online_status" in your code instead of the column "online".

Comment: Yes seems like this is the only way

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature exists in neither Postgres nor the SQL. I think this is a quite interesting question so I googled a little bit and came across an interesting article on [postgresonline.com](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/41-How-to-SELECT-ALL-EXCEPT-some-columns-in-a-table.html).

They show an approach that selects the columns directly from the schema:

```
  SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT 'o' || '.' || c.column_name
          FROM information_schema.columns As c
              WHERE table_name = 'officepark' 
              AND c.column_name NOT IN('officeparkid', 'contractor')
      ), ',') || ' FROM officepark As o' As sqlstmt
```

You could create a function that does something like that. Such topics were also discussed on the mailing lists, but the overall consensus was pretty much the same: query the schema.

I'm sure that there are other solutions but I think they will all involve some kind of magic schema-querying-foo.

BTW: Be careful with `SELECT * ...` as this can have performance penalties

Comment: `Such a feature exists in neither Postgres nor the SQL.` I would be more cautious with such statements. `SELECT * EXCEPT ...` exists.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: but not "in SQL" (as that refers to the SQL standard)